# Laravel ajax POST 404 (Not Found)

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel

I'm creating searching function for my table in my laravel project. I'm using ajax live search method but facing some error now when insert into the search bar. The errors shown in console are POST 404 (not found). 
My post is below. I'm not sure why this has stopped working.

Sorry for my bad English.

**This is my script**

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  load_data();

  function load_data (query)
  {
    $.ajax({
      url:"fetch.php",
      method:"POST",
      data:{query:query},
       success:function(data)
      {
        $('#table').html(data);
      }
    });
  }

  $('#search').keyup(function(){
  var search = $(this).val();
  if(search != '')
  {
   load_data(search);
  }
  else
  {
   load_data();
  }
 });
```

**fetch.php**

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST["query"]))
{ 
$connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "testing");
$request = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $_POST["query"]);
$query = "
  SELECT * FROM domain
  WHERE Domain LIKE '%".$request."%'
";
$result = mysqli_query($connect, $query);
$html = '';
$data = array();
$html .= '
      <table class="table table-bordered table-striped">
        <tr>
          <th>Domain</th>
          <th>Registrar</th>
          <th>Login ID</th> 
          <th>Password</th>
        </tr>
    ';
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) 
    {
      $data[] = $row["Domain"];
      $data[] = $row["Registrar"];
      $data[] = $row["Login_ID"];
      $data[] = $row["Password"];
      $html .= '
        <tr>
          <td>'.$row["Domain"].'</td>
          <td>'.$row["Registrar"].'</td>
          <td>'.$row["Login_ID"].'</td>
          <td>'.$row["Password"].'</td>
         </tr>
      ';
    }
    $html .= '</table>';

    if (isset($_POST["typehead_search"])) 
    {
      echo $html;
    }
    else 
    {
      $data = array_unique($data);
      echo json_encode($data);
    }    
}
?>
```

Comment: Can you share the exact error? And can you shorten your `fetch.php` so it just prints something simple for now since the issue seems to be the JS hitting the PHP file rather than the PHP file itself.

Comment: is this code really written in laravel?

Comment: Looks like you wrote everything in plain php.

Answer (score 0):

Your `url` is incorrect. You need to create a `route` to a `controller` in you `routes/web.php` file. In your case you could create a controller called `AjaxController` with a `public function Search(Request $request)`.

Then your route would look something like this:

```
Route::post('/ajax/search', 'AjaxController@search');
```

In your `$.ajax` call the `url` would be `'/ajax/search'`.

The laravel documentation is quite elaborate on this topic, so you might want to head over to:  [laravel route](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/routing) . If you have done this already and still have more questions, don't be affraid to ask :)